# Errores con los archivos en ejecutables python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo ejecutable a partir de un programa que he hecho. Estoy utilizando pyinstaller para ello (version 4.8). Por lo que tengo entendido, tengo que pasarle a la lista `datas` del archivo .spec que se genera la ruta de los archivos, y "arreglar" la ruta en el programa (he copiado este código que aparecía en la respuesta a otra pregunta)

```
def resolver_ruta(ruta_relativa):
    try:
        ruta_base = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        ruta_base = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(ruta_base, ruta_relativa)
```

El problema es que al abrir el archivo ejecutable, me salta el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 263, in <module>
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 246, in imagen
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 35, in __init__
  File "PIL/Image.py", line 2975, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/7y/t5scg2bn301bg3c7zgd886nm0000gq/T/_MEIKGpFTb/archivos_buscaminas/boom.jpg'
[2215] Failed to execute script 'Buscaminas' due to unhandled exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/7y/t5scg2bn301bg3c7zgd886nm0000gq/T/_MEIKGpFTb/archivos_buscaminas/boom.jpg'
[2215] Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 263, in <module>
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 246, in imagen
  File "Buscaminas.py", line 35, in __init__
  File "PIL/Image.py", line 2975, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/7y/t5scg2bn301bg3c7zgd886nm0000gq/T/_MEIKGpFTb/archivos_buscaminas/boom.jpg'
```

Dejo el archivo .spec y el programa por si sirve de ayuda. Mi versión de python es la 3.10.0 Gracias por adelantado.

Buscaminas.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random as rnd
import multiprocessing
import playsound
import os, sys

estado_partida = "jugando"

def imagen_mainloop(ventana):
    ventana.mainloop()

def sonido_aplausos():
    playsound.playsound(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/aplausos.mp3"))

def sonido_explosion():
    playsound.playsound(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/explosion.mp3"))

def imagen(ventana, sonido_aplausos_process, sonido_explosion_process):
    class app():

        def __init__(self):
            
            self.sonido_aplausos_process = sonido_aplausos_process
            self.sonido_explosion_process = sonido_explosion_process

            ventana.update()

            self.centro = int(ventana.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - 500)

            ventana.geometry(f"1000x1000+{self.centro}+0")
            ventana.minsize(1000, 1000)
            ventana.maxsize(1000, 1000)

            explosion = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/boom.jpg"))
            explosion = explosion.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.explosion = ImageTk.PhotoImage(explosion)

            bandera = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/bandera.png"))
            bandera = bandera.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.bandera = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bandera)

            casilla_1 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas1.png"))
            casilla_1 = casilla_1.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_1)

            casilla_2 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas2.png"))
            casilla_2 = casilla_2.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_2)

            casilla_3 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas3.png"))
            casilla_3 = casilla_3.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_3)

            casilla_4 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas4.png"))
            casilla_4 = casilla_4.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_4)

            casilla_5 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas5.png"))
            casilla_5 = casilla_5.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_5)

            casilla_6 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas6.png"))
            casilla_6 = casilla_6.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_6)

            casilla_7 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas7.png"))
            casilla_7 = casilla_7.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_7)

            casilla_8 = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas8.png"))
            casilla_8 = casilla_8.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.casilla_8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(casilla_8)

            blanco = Image.open(resolver_ruta("archivos_buscaminas/blanco100x100.png"))
            blanco = blanco.resize((98, 98), Image.BICUBIC)
            self.blanco = ImageTk.PhotoImage(blanco)

            self.lista_num = [self.blanco, self.casilla_1, self.casilla_2, self.casilla_3, self.casilla_4, self.casilla_5, self.casilla_6, self.casilla_7, self.casilla_8, self.explosion]

            self.num_minas_cerca = {}
            for i in range(10):
                for j in range(10):
                    self.num_minas_cerca[f"{i + 1}_{j + 1}"] = 0

            self.estado_casilla = {}
            for i in range(10):
                for j in range(10):
                    self.estado_casilla[f"{i + 1}_{j + 1}"] = "no revelado"

            self.fondo = tk.Canvas(width=1000, height=1000, bg="grey77")
            self.fondo.place(x=0, y=0)
            self.x = 100
            self.y = 100
            for i in range(9):
                self.fondo.create_line(self.x, 0 , self.x, 1000, width=1, fill = "grey")
                self.x += 100

            for i in range(9):
                self.fondo.create_line(0, self.y, 1000, self.y, width=1, fill = "grey")
                self.y += 100

            self.estatus = "jugando"

            self.lista_minas = []


            self.NUMERO_MINAS = 13
            for i in range(0, self.NUMERO_MINAS):
                self.pos_mina_x = rnd.randint(1, 10)
                self.pos_mina_y = rnd.randint(1, 10)
                self.pos_mina = (self.pos_mina_x, self.pos_mina_y)

                for i in self.lista_minas:
                    while i == self.pos_mina:
                        self.pos_mina_x = rnd.randint(1, 10)
                        self.pos_mina_y = rnd.randint(1, 10)
                        self.pos_mina = (self.pos_mina_x, self.pos_mina_y)
                self.lista_minas.append(self.pos_mina)
            print(self.lista_minas)

            for mina in self.lista_minas:
                self.num_minas_cerca[f"{mina[0]}_{mina[1]}"] = -1
                for i in range(-1, 2):
                    for j in range(-1, 2):
                        if mina[0] + i > 0 and mina[0] + i < 11 and mina[1] + j > 0 and mina[1] + j < 11:
                            if not self.num_minas_cerca[f"{mina[0] + i}_{mina[1] + j}"] == -1:
                                self.num_minas_cerca[f"{mina[0] + i}_{mina[1] + j}"] += 1
            
            self.casilla_click = ()

            self.fondo.bind('<Button-1>', self.combineFunc(self.click, self.comprobar_casilla))

            self.fondo.bind("<Button-2>", self.combineFunc(self.click, self.poner_bandera))

            


    
        def click(self, event):

            coordenadas_click = event.x, event.y

            casilla_click_x = coordenadas_click[0]
            casilla_click_y = coordenadas_click[1]
            i = 0
            while casilla_click_x >= 0:
                casilla_click_x -= 100
                i += 1
            casilla_click_x = i
            i = 0
            while casilla_click_y >= 0:
                casilla_click_y -= 100
                i += 1
            casilla_click_y = i

            casilla_click = casilla_click_x, casilla_click_y
            self.casilla_click = casilla_click
            print(casilla_click)

        
        def comprobar_casilla(self, event):
            lista_minas = self.lista_minas
            casilla_click = self.casilla_click
            lista_blancas = []

            def revelar_en_cadena(self, lista):
                quedan_blancas = True
                while quedan_blancas:
                    for casilla in lista:
                        lista.remove(casilla)
                        for i in range(-1, 2):
                            for j in range(-1, 2):
                                if casilla[0] + i > 0 and casilla[0] + i < 11 and casilla[1] + j > 0 and casilla[1] + j < 11 and not self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla[0] + i}_{casilla[1] + j}"] == "revelado":
                                    self.fondo.create_image(int((casilla[0] + i) * 100 - 98), int((casilla[1] + j) * 100 - 98), image = self.lista_num[self.num_minas_cerca[f"{casilla[0] + i}_{casilla[1] + j}"]], anchor = "nw")
                                    if self.num_minas_cerca[f"{casilla[0] + i}_{casilla[1] + j}"] == 0:
                                        lista.append((casilla[0] + i, casilla[1] + j))
                                    self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla[0] + i}_{casilla[1] + j}"] = "revelado"
                    if len(lista) == 0:
                        quedan_blancas = False

            if casilla_click in lista_minas:
                for mina in lista_minas:
                    if casilla_click == mina:
                        self.fondo.create_image(int(casilla_click[0] * 100 - 98), int(casilla_click[1] * 100 - 98), image = self.explosion, anchor = "nw")
                        self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] = "revelado"
                        self.estatus = "fin_derrota"
                        globals()["estado_partida"] = "derrota"
                        self.sonido_explosion_process.start()


            elif self.num_minas_cerca[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] == 0 and not self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] == "revelado":
                self.fondo.create_image(int(casilla_click[0] * 100 - 98), int(casilla_click[1] * 100 - 98), image = self.blanco, anchor = "nw")
                lista_blancas.append((casilla_click[0], casilla_click[1]))
                self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] = "revelado"
                revelar_en_cadena(self, lista_blancas)

            elif self.num_minas_cerca[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] > 0 and not self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] == "revelado":
                self.fondo.create_image(int((casilla_click[0]) * 100 - 98), int((casilla_click[1]) * 100 - 98), image = self.lista_num[self.num_minas_cerca[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"]], anchor = "nw")
                self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] = "revelado"

            if self.estatus == "fin_derrota":
                for i in range(1, 11):
                    for j in range(1, 11):
                        self.fondo.create_image((i * 100 - 98), (j * 100 - 98), image = self.lista_num[self.num_minas_cerca[f"{i}_{j}"]], anchor = "nw")
                        self.estado_casilla[f"{i}_{j}"] = "revelado"


        def poner_bandera(self, event):
            lista_minas = self.lista_minas
            casilla_click = self.casilla_click

            if self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] == "no revelado":
                self.fondo.create_image(int((casilla_click[0]) * 100 - 98), int((casilla_click[1]) * 100 - 98), image = self.bandera, anchor = "nw", tag = f"bandera{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}")
                self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] = "bandera"

                minas_con_bandera = 0
                for mina in lista_minas:
                    if self.estado_casilla[f"{mina[0]}_{mina[1]}"] == "bandera":
                        minas_con_bandera += 1

                casillas_con_bandera = 0
                for estado in self.estado_casilla.values():
                    if estado == "bandera":
                            casillas_con_bandera += 1
                print(casillas_con_bandera, minas_con_bandera)
                if casillas_con_bandera == self.NUMERO_MINAS and minas_con_bandera == self.NUMERO_MINAS:
                    if __name__ == "__main__":
                        self.sonido_aplausos_process.start()
                        globals()["estado_partida"] = "gana"
                

            elif self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] == "bandera":
                self.fondo.delete(f"bandera{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}")
                self.estado_casilla[f"{casilla_click[0]}_{casilla_click[1]}"] = "no revelado"



        def combineFunc(self, *funcs):
            def combinedFunc(*args, **kwargs):
                for f in funcs:
                    f(*args, **kwargs)
            return combinedFunc
    

    app()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def resolver_ruta(ruta_relativa):
        try:
            ruta_base = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            ruta_base = os.path.abspath(".")
        return os.path.join(ruta_base, ruta_relativa)

    ventana = tk.Tk()

    sonido_aplausos_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = sonido_aplausos)
    sonido_explosion_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = sonido_explosion)

    imagen(ventana, sonido_aplausos_process, sonido_explosion_process)

    imagen_process = multiprocessing.Process(target= imagen_mainloop(ventana))

    imagen_process.start()

    imagen_process.join()

    if estado_partida == "gana":
        sonido_aplausos_process.kill()

    elif estado_partida == "derrota":
        sonido_explosion_process.kill()
```

Buscaminas.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Proyectos/Buscaminas.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [
    ("aplausos.mp3", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/aplausos.mp3", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("bandera.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/bandera.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("blanco100x100.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/blanco100x100.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("boom.jpg", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/boom.jpg", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas1.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas1.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas2.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas2.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas3.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas3.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas4.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas4.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas5.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas5.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas6.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas6.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas7.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas7.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("buscaminas8.png", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/buscaminas8.png", "archivos_buscaminas"),
    ("explosion.mp3", "file:///Users/administrador/Desktop/VISUAL_STUDIO_CODE/archivos_buscaminas/explosion.mp3", "archivos_buscaminas"),
]

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='Buscaminas',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='Buscaminas.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Comment: En la función `resolver_ruta` tienes un try-except que usa la clase Exception. Si no me equivoco, eso captura el error una sola vez. Probaste por cambiar `except Exception` por `except BaseException`, recompilar el exe y volver a probar?

Comment: Hola! Acabo de probarlo y me sigue dando el mismo error. Gracias por tu respuesta.